# Meteor Blaze {{if}} statement to check if array

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have collection that has a document object "wageringStraightSpread" that sometimes is an embedded array. I need to check then look through the array, but i am not sure of the syntax of the {{if}} statement. I am specifically looking for help with this line {{#if team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread = array}}. Thank you!

Here's what I got:

```
{{#if team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread = array}}
    {{#each}}
           {{team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread.this.line}}
           ({{team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread.this.money}})
     {{/each}}
 {{else}}
          {{team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread.line}}
          ({{team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread.money}})
{{/if}}
```

Comment: You need to have a helper for the condition checking

Comment: What does that helper look like? I already have a helper for template to even display the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `isArray` helper that does the check:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  isArray: function(a){
    return Array.isArray(a);
  }
});
```

And use it from your html with:

```
{{#if isArray someVariable}}
```

Comment: MIchel, I am going to assume that you mean {#if checkArray someVariable}} and by someVariable do you mean the chained object? Also when checking my other {{team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread.this.line}} I am not allowed to use "this" to loop through the array. what can I use?

Comment: Sorry, made the comment match the helper name. If `this` is an array then you can use it in an `{{#each this}}` loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `if` condition is wrong. it is supposed to `==`, not `=`. However, that is not the case, because `if` of Meteor template does not support boolean operation. Therefore, you will have to have a helper for this

```
Template.layout.helpers({
   checkArray: function() {
      // return the result of the comparison of 
      // team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread == array. 
      // you do need to find the way to compare the array since == is also wrong 
      // for comparing the array 
   }
});

{{#if checkArray}}

{{/if}}
```